# Does OAuth authentication of google account which is registered after April 20,2015 return openid_id?

Tags: oauth, google-openid, openid-connect

I am developing a website by using OpenID2 and I will use Oauth.
Now every new users by using OpenID2 of google can get openid_id.
But I don't know that new users by using google account registered after April 20,2015.

example flow is following:

- Person A registers new google account(account name: hogeA, email: hogeA@google.com) on April 21, 2015
- Person A registers my website's account by using 'hogeA'(by using OAuth2)

Comment: You should not use OpenID 2.0 any more.  It is deprecated.  If you want to support Google logins, you need to use OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

openid_id will continue to be returned for Google OpenID migration flows until January 2017 as per [Google's migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable).

Having said that, your application should be using Google's global user identifiers (see [sub parameter in id token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo)) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My project will use Google's global user identifiers